# "(" is not valid at this postition in this sever version

Tags: mysql

I do want to insert data into my Google Cloud database with using MySQL, I did it fairly well with others table expect this one.

My database structure :

- item_id int(11) primary key - autoincrement
- bill_id int(11) foreign key
- name text
- unit text
- quantity int(11)
- usage long text
- price float

`INSERT INTO BillItem (bill_id , name , unit , quantity , price,usage) VALUES ('8','Mebendazol 500 mg','Viên','5','2500','Chiều trước khi ăn') ;`

Again, thank you a bunch for your assistance!

Comment: Did you try insert query in my workbench?

Comment: @HienNguyen I did it and received this error, I got an issue on Visual Studio : ": `'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'usage,price) VALUES (9, 'Mebendazol 500 mg','Viên',20,'Trưa sau khi ăn',10000' at line 1'"`

Comment: `('8'` Why are you quoting numbers like that?

Comment: My query in my workbench `INSERT INTO BillItem(bill_id,name,unit,quantity,usage,price) VALUES (13,'Acetylcystein 200 mg','Kem bôi',20,'Trưa sau khi ăn',14000);`  my code in VS : 
            `String query = string.Format("INSERT INTO BillItem(bill_id,name,unit,quantity,usage,price) VALUES " +
             "({0}, '{1}','{2}',{3},'{4}',{5})",
              billId, name, un, quan,use,pr);`

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue here is you are using reserved word: `usage`

Refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-U

To fix this avoid using reserved word, otherwise use backticks around the reserved word.
`` `usage` ``

Comment: I'm so sorry for asking you further about my problem, `String query = string.Format("INSERT INTO BillItem(bill_id,medName,unit,quantity,howtoUSE,price) VALUES " +
             "({0}, '{1}','{2}',{3},'{4}',{5})",
              billId, name, un, quan,use,pr);`. I got a new issue with "Unknown column 'Bill.medicine' in 'field list'', in spite of not having this colummn name in my field list.

Comment: @LắcLê, sorry I'm not sure not enough detail to see the issue. I would recommend you create another question regarding this. With the relevant information.